# Readonly configuration variables ini file

Tags: python, parsing, configuration

I have a program in python that has an ini file with the configuration variables for the program. Some variables are ReadWrite and others ReadOnly.

My config file is something like this:

```
[AuthCtrlr]
enable = True
nbrOfMssgs = 10
```

where I want the variable `enable` to be ReadWrite and `nbrOfMssgs`  ReadOnly.

In my python code, I can change my variables with:

```
parser.set('AuthCtrlr', 'enable', False)
```

with the [`configparser`](https://pypi.org/project/configparser/) module.

Is there a way to make a code where if I want to change the variable `nbrOfMssgs` it prints something like "This variable is ReadOnly" and don't change the value of the variable?

Comment: @matszwecja sorry, how do you do this?

Comment: Is there really a need for making variables read only? You yourself seem to write the program, are you trying to protect yourself from yourself? Isn't this a UI issue?

Comment: Another issue with ini files is that they are basically *input* that has to be evaluated. Not allowing changes within the program doesn't prevent changes from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import configparser

class wrappedParser(configparser.ConfigParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.readOnlySettings = []
    def set(self, category, setting, value):
        if setting in self.readOnlySettings:
            raise PermissionError(f"{setting} setting is read-only")
        else:
            return super().set(category, setting, value)
    def makeReadOnly(self, setting):
        self.readOnlySettings.append(setting)



config = wrappedParser()
config['bitbucket.org'] = {}
config.set('bitbucket.org', 'User', 'hg')
config.makeReadOnly('User')
try:
    config.set('bitbucket.org', 'User', 'pg')
except PermissionError as err:
    print(err)
print(config.get('bitbucket.org', 'User'))
```

Make a child class inheriting from ConfigParser that reimplements set operation in a way that raises an error if the setting you are trying to change is one of the read-only ones.

Still, this does not in any way improve security of your code. It's only good to prevent you from *accidentially* changing the settings. Which asks the question, why would that happen?

Comment: This is a good approach, although the more or less free write access to the configuration from outside remains a problem.